# How to call a class in c#

Tags: c#, class

I have a function in a separate class called dopurge, I would like to call this class in like you would call an instantiable class in java, I would normally use,

```
dopurge myPurge = new dopurge ();
```

can anybody tell me how to do this for c# please.

Comment: You've already done it.

Comment: You don't call a class. You call a method, or a constructor, or a property getter/setter etc. And you've already got code to call a constructor in your question.

Comment: Same way as you do in Java.

Comment: if(this.IKnow == "Crazy")  CallMe.Maybe();

Comment: Additionally, please note that in C#, class names should start with capital letters, just like method names. Your class would be `DoPurge` and a possible method name would be `Purge`.

Comment: Why do people minus the questions, that was a genuine question, I couldnt get it to work so I presumed it was something different, It makes you not want to ask a question again

Comment: @user2703960, do not be put off. However, this generally happens when the answer can be found in either a) a tutorial or b) a Google search or c) a search here. Your question showed you did **absolutely none of this**. So please, do keep asking questions **where reasonable**. If you don't do the research yourself, how will you understand the language **properly**?

Comment: @Arran Hi, I did research (not a lot) but I couldnt find it, I understand you, Thanks for your reply, I will get the hang of StackOverflow soon :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already done it, the way it is supposed.

Now you can call your methods with `myPurge.TeachMeCSharp(MSDN)`